# Python: What is the best way to effectively change the subclass of an instance (keeping the original instances' variables)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, subclass

I am not a very great or experienced Python coder, and I'm wondering if there's an easy way to do what I need to do. But I haven't been able to find anything on my own because I'm not sure how to phrase the question properly.

The situation I have is more or less as follows:

```
class Insect:
  def __init__(self, arg1):
    self.arg1 = arg1

  def insect_method(self):
    print('do insect stuff')

class Caterpillar(Insect):
  def __init__(self, arg1):
    super().__init__(arg1)

  def caterpillar_method(self):
    print('do caterpillar stuff')

class Butterfly(Insect):
  def __init__(self, arg1, arg2):
    super().__init__(arg1)
    self.arg2 = arg2

  def butterfly_method(self):
    print('do butterfly stuff')
```

I'm not actually simulating caterpillars and butterflies, but it's a similar process so I thought it might help make things clearer.

I have a super class 'Insect' which is never created by itself but exists so subclasses can inherit its methods. Most of the time, I am just spawning the subclasses directly and that's it. But I have a special case where the Caterpillar subclass should become an instance of the Butterfly subclass.

I have searched, and been convinced that changing `__class__` is probably not what I want to do in the long run. However, I am also not sure if there's an elegant way to do this otherwise?

The only technique I can think of at the moment is to add in a bunch of `if` statements like this:

```
class Insect:
  def __init__(self, arg1):
    self.arg1 = arg1

  def insect_method(self):
    print('do insect stuff')

class Caterpillar(Insect):
  def __init__(self, arg1):
    super().__init__(arg1)

  def caterpillar_method(self):
    print('do caterpillar stuff')

class Butterfly(Insect):
  def __init__(self, arg1, arg2, caterpillar=None):
    if not caterpillar:
        super().__init__(arg1)
    else:
        self.arg1 = caterpillar.arg1
    self.arg2 = arg2

  def butterfly_method(self):
    print('do butterfly stuff')
```

This would work if the actual code was as simple as this, but it's not, so I'd end up having to make a kind of double of the `Insect.__init__` method in the `Butterfly.__init__` method and then would have to make sure to constantly update both methods whenever changing anything in the `Insect.__init__` method.

Is there an elegant Pythonic method to have this kind of functionality without needing to create a very convoluted `__init__` method for the Butterfly class?

Many thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Are you sure you don't want `Butterfly` to be a child of `Caterpillar`? If you don't want to do this, then I'd suggest a `Caterpillar.become_butterfly()` method that returns a `Butterfly` instance that you can replace your original instance with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of putting this logic in your `__init__`, I'd maybe keep the `__init__` simple and put the logic to create a `Butterfly` from a `Caterpillar` in a `classmethod`:

```
class Butterfly(Insect):
    def __init__(self, arg1, arg2):
        super().__init__(arg1)
        self.arg2 = arg2

    @classmethod
    def from_caterpillar(cls, caterpillar, arg2):
        return cls(caterpillar.arg1, arg2)
```

Then you might have code that does something like:

```
bob = Caterpillar("Bob")
# metamorphose
bob = Butterfly.from_caterpillar(bob, "Small")
```

Note that similar to your original code, this doesn't mutate the original `Caterpillar` object to make it a `Butterfly`, it creates a new `Butterfly` instance (and reassigns `bob` to it).

Comment: Thank you, all the answers were good and informative but yours probably helps me the best in not having to rewrite all the current architecture of this project.

I can't exactly do it your way because there are a number of variables that are not arguments but are set in the ```Insect.__init__``` to random values which need to be preserved between caterpillars and butterflies. But that's on me for not specifying this in my simplified example.

Answer (score 2):

There are two separate notions here: butterfly the species, and butterfly the adult stage of that specie's lifestyle. In a pure functional language with linear types, you might have a function that takes a caterpillar, produces a butterfly, *and* ensures that you cannot use that caterpillar instance ever again.

In Python, I might define the following classes:

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod


class Stage(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def do_something(self):
        ...


class Caterpillar(Stage):
    def do_something(self):
        print("do caterpillar stuff")
    

class AdultButterfly(Stage):
    def do_something(self):
        print("do butterfly stuff")
    

class Butterfly(Insect):
    def __init__(self):
        self.stage = Caterpillar()

    def do_something(self):
        return self.stage.do_something()

    def growup(self):
        self.stage = AdultButterfly()
```

This allows an instance of `Butterfly` to *transition* from caterpillar to (adult) butterfly without

1. Creating an adult butterfly from thin air, or
2. Creating multiple adult butterflies from a single caterpillar

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways of doing this. Probably the most readable and "clean" (well... at least to me) are the `@classmethod`s: Either through a `from_caterpillar` classmethod in the `Butterfly` proposed by @Samwise in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75951002/289011), or have a `become_butterfly` classmethod in your `Caterpillar` as proposed by @Pranav Hosangadi in [one of the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75950919/python-what-is-the-best-way-to-effectively-change-the-subclass-of-an-instance#comment133960829_75950919).

I just wanted to introduce you to the [isinstance](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-isinstance-method/) method.

With that, if you could make the `Butterfly`'s constructor accept a "whatever" OR an instance of a `Caterpillar` as `arg1`, you could do something like the following:

```
class Butterfly(Insect):
    def __init__(self, arg1, arg2):
        if isinstance(arg1, Caterpillar):
            print("OMG! Metamorphosed!! Digievolution!")
            super().__init__(arg1.arg1)
            # Or just:
            # self.arg1 = arg1. arg1
        else:
            super().__init__(arg1)

        self.arg2 = arg2
```